# error when executing find command using variable

Tags: bash, scripting, find

I have written a `find` command to copy some source files:

```
find ./lib ./tools -type f -regex '.*\.\(cpp\|c\|h\)$' -exec cp --parents \{\} /tmp/potato \; -print
```

This works well, but I also want to add the trailing `-print` optionally, so I do something like this:

```
function deploy_source_code {
    exec_cmd="find ./lib ./tools -type f -regex '.*\.\(cpp\|c\|h\)$' -exec cp --parents \{\} ${args[destdir]} \;"
    if [ "${args[verbose]}" = "true" ]; then
        exec_cmd="${exec_cmd} -print"
    fi  
    ${exec_cmd}
}
```

But it happens to fail with error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I don't know why it fails and I would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally relevant: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use an array and execute it as the arguments to a simple command.

```
deploy_source_code() {
  exec_cmd=(find ./lib ./tools -type f -regex '.*\.\(cpp\|c\|h\)$' 
    -exec cp --parents {} "${args[destdir]}" \;)
  if [ "${args[verbose]}" = "true" ]; then
    exec_cmd+=(-print)
  fi  
  "${exec_cmd[@]}"
}
```

Or a string and evaluate it as shell code:

```
deploy_source_code() {
  exec_cmd="find ./lib ./tools -type f -regex '.*\.\(cpp\|c\|h\)$' \
    -exec cp --parents {} \"\${args[destdir]}\" \;"
  if [ "${args[verbose]}" = "true" ]; then
    exec_cmd+=" -print"
  fi  
  eval "$exec_cmd"
}
```

Note that in the code above, it's important to make sure the `${args[destdir]}` is not expanded at the time of assignment as otherwise its content would be passed to `eval` to be evaluated as shell code! It can be hard to use `eval` safely, I'd go with the array approach especially considering you're already using associative arrays.

In your approach, you were using the split+glob operator on your string to make the arguments of a simple command. That didn't work because the last argument to `find` was `\;` instead of just `;` (and you'd also have problems with the literal quote characters passed to `find`). You could use the split+glob operator as:

```
deploy_source_code() {
  exec_cmd="find ./lib ./tools -type f -regex .*\.\(cpp\|c\|h\)$ \
    -exec cp --parents {} ${args[destdir]} ;"
  if [ "${args[verbose]}" = "true" ]; then
    exec_cmd+=" -print"
  fi
  IFS=" " # split on space
  set -f  # disable glob
  $exec_cmd # invoke the split+glob operator
}
```

But that means it won't work if `${args[destdir]}` contains space characters. You could always replace those spaces with a character that is less likely to occur in `${args[destdir]}` like `:` or newline.

Comment: thanks! I decided to use the `eval` command